# Custom dojo build with dojo-util package from bower

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo-build

When retrieving the `dojo-util` package from bower, the package is installed in a directory `dojo-util/..`, but when running the command line to create a custom build, it complains that the `main.js` file could not be found.

The file the compiler search for should be located in `/util/build/main.js`, but when installing with bower the dirname is `/dojo-util/build/main.js`.

Someone already had this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve this by instructing bower to install dojo-util as util:

```
bower install util=dojo-util#<version>
```

Or in bower.json's `dependencies`:

```
"util": "dojo-util#<version>"
```